# Layout TYPO3-Extension Backend

Tags: typo3, backend, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I need to add a hr-like tag in the TCA of my Extension Backend or a linebreak. Is this possible in some way?

I've tried `--linebreak--` in my palettes, but this did not work. Checked for the changes in Admin->Configuration. There comes the `--linebreak--` but it does not do anything in the Ext-Backend.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe supply a screenshot of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us the reason for the `<hr>` tag you need?

One simple way would be to use the `USER` type of the TCA where you are able to render any HTML. It is described here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html

Comment: Well my client is a bit difficult and he doesn't want TABS but one single page with dividers.. Thank you for your answer I will def give it a try haven't heard about this type!

Comment: Removing the tabs can be possible in 6.x by using this TCA: `$GLOBALS['TCA']['<table name>']['ctrl']['dividers2tabs']` this doesn't work with 7 anymore. 

Maybe this helps you

Comment: thanks but the tabs were easy to remove, done that before a few times but never customised input fields in BE